# print_r functionality in iPython

Tags: php, python, object, ipython

Is there a way to get PHP-like `print_r(object)` funcionality in iPython?

I know I can use '?' to get info about an object, but how do I view the *values* of the object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is

```
print my_object.__dict__
```

perhaps what you are looking for?

Or have a look at [the standard python pretty printer](http://docs.python.org/library/pprint.html) for more advanced, recursive printing.

Comment: but don't actually name your object "object", since that has a special meaning in Python

Comment: @Triptych I used the term that user27... also used. But I'll correct it so people new to python won't get confused.

Answer (score 2):

`dir(object)` will give you all its attribute names.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use the `pprint` module if you want it to be nicely formatted:

```
import pprint
obj = {'a':1, 'b':2}
pprint.pprint(obj)
```

Answer (score 0):

[`repr()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#repr) calls the `__repr__()` method of the object, which usually gives some information about the contents of the object if written appropriately.